# Single Page of Custom Post Type Not Showing the Content Of post

Tags: custom-post-types, single

I have a single post type called `BlogsCPT` which I am able to loop through it by following code at `page-blogs.php`

```
 <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'BlogsCPT');
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        echo '<h4 style="font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;">'. get_the_title().'</h4>';
        echo '<p class="p-paragraph-excerpt">'. get_the_excerpt().'</p>';
        echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" role="button" class="btn">Read More &gt;&gt;</a>';
    endwhile;
 ?>
```

but when I try to get into the single post page by using

```
echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" role="button" class="btn">Read More &gt;&gt;</a>';
```

and `single-BlogsCPT.php` which is:

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
    echo '<h4>'. get_the_title().'</h4>';
    echo '<h6>'. get_post_time('l, F j, Y').'</h6>';
    echo '<p class="p-paragraph">'. get_the_content().'</p>';
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

clicking on the button redirect the url to

```
http://domain.ca/blogscpt/my-today-post/
```

but it is not showing anything from the post! Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Update

```
function cpt_Blogs() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                 => 'Blogs',
        'singular_name'        => 'Blog',
        'menu_name'            => 'Blogs',
        'name_admin_bar'       => 'Blogs',
        'parent_item_colon'    => 'Parent Blogs:',
        'all_items'            => 'All Blogs',
        'view_item'            => 'View Blog',
        'add_new_item'         => 'Add New Blog',
        'add_new'              => 'Add New Blog',
        'new_item'             => 'New Blogs',
        'edit_item'            => 'Edit Blog Item',
        'update_item'          => 'Update Blog Item',
        'search_items'         => 'Search Blog Item',
        'not_found'            => 'Blog Not found',
        'not_found_in_trash'   => 'Blog Not found in Trash',
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                => 'BlogsCPT',
        'description'          => 'This Post Type Adds Blogs to Website',
        'labels'               => $labels,
        'supports'             => array( 'title', 'thumbnail', 'editor','excerpt'),
        'taxonomies'           => array( 'BlogsTax' ),
        'hierarchical'         => true,
        'public'               => true,
        'show_ui'              => true,
        'show_in_menu'         => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'    => true,
        'menu_position'        => 5,
        'can_export'           => true,
        'has_archive'          => true,
        'exclude_from_search'  => false,
        'publicly_queryable'   => true,
        'capability_type'      => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'BlogsCPT', $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'cpt_Blogs', 0 );
```

Comment: Note that when you register the post type, the slug must be lower-case.

Comment: Hi birgire, thanks for reply but can you please let me know which option of CPT is taking care of this?

Comment: Look for the [`register_post_type(  'BlogsCPT', $args  )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) call. The first input argument  *"Post type key. Must not exceed 20 characters and may only contain lowercase alphanumeric characters, dashes, and underscores. "*

Comment: I just updated the post with my custom post type. can you please take a look at there?